# How to convert a 3d zmap tiff image to a color bitmap or Image<Bgr,byte>?

Tags: c#, opencv, signal-processing, emgucv

I have a few images from a 3D scanner of a grinding disc. I want to view the image in a picturebox. I use this code :

```
        Mat finalImage = test3dimg.Clone();    
        // Normalize the image to 0-255 range
        CvInvoke.Normalize(finalImage, finalImage, 150, 255, NormType.MinMax);
        // Convert the image data type to 8-bit unsigned integer
        finalImage.ConvertTo(finalImage, DepthType.Cv8U);
        CvInvoke.Resize(finalImage, finalImage, new Size(), 1.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 1.5);
        // Apply the Jet colormap to the image
        CvInvoke.ApplyColorMap(finalImage, finalImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ColorMapType.Jet);
        imagebox3D.Image = finalImage.ToBitmap();
```

But this just shows the image as below :

[image]

Where as it should be looking like this ;

[image]

How do I convert a 3d tiff image or a Mat to a jet colorspace image? Here is the link to download the sample file - https://filebin.net/w209nb9q3epv4s38

Comment: can you provide input data and enough code to represent a [mre]?

Comment: Have edited my question to include the link to download a sample file. Thats the code I have, I load the image and convert it to Mat. and then the above code comes into play.

Comment: I hope an answer five days later is still useful to you

Answer (score 0):

The file contains values ranging from 0 to 28.6, but also values of -1000.

You see "nothing" after `normalize()` because most of the output range is wasted trying to map down to -1000.

Simply scale manually.

This is 0 .. 29 stretched to 0.0 .. 1.0:

[image: 0 .. 29]

This is 23 .. 28. You can faintly see the grid pattern.

[image: 23 .. 28]

That is presented as grayscale. If you want a color map, OpenCV can do it with `cv::applyColorMap()`.

Further reading:

- [windowing of X-Ray values](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=CT_scan&useskin=vector#Windowing)

Comment: Hi,, The output looks great. I did not understand what you mean by scaling the values. Can you give a code example of what you did here. Colormap is not necessary as i would be thresholding the image for the grid pattern anyways.

Comment: I don't speak C# so I can't give you example code in C#. you should figure out how to access individual elements of the image. as an exercise, find the minimum and maximum, once with `cv::minMaxLoc` and once with an explicit loop going over each element. -- thresholding will not work. the disc's surface isn't exactly parallel.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. You can also give me examples in any programming language you may have tried with opencv, I understand most of them and can convert them to my usecase.

Comment: this is a point cloud. you have the Z for each point, but they're still in the "image plane" grid, so you'd need to project them outwards. then you could select only those points belonging to the disc (roughly thresholding by distance?), then fit a plane through them, then take each point's distance to that plane. that will let you threshold this thing nicely.